# Removing an item from systemd startup

Tags: startup, systemd

My boot time is very high and when I use

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

I get the following result

```
     25.282s home-arianhf-google\x2ddrive.mount
     23.567s systemd-journal-flush.service
     23.232s dev-sda9.device
```

and the result of `systemctl list-units --type=mount` 
is :

```
UNIT                                    LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                                    
  -.mount                                 loaded active mounted Root Mount                                     
  dev-hugepages.mount                     loaded active mounted Huge Pages File System                         
  dev-mqueue.mount                        loaded active mounted POSIX Message Queue File System                
● home-arianhf-google\x2ddrive.mount      loaded failed failed  /home/arianhf/google-drive                     
  mnt-ubuntu.mount                        loaded active mounted /mnt/ubuntu                                    
  proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount           loaded active mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System
```

notice the failed mount.

i want to remove this from my systemd. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
sudo systemctl disable home-arianhf-google\x2ddrive.mount
```

For more info check the man page of systemctl.

Also check `etc/fstab` for any relevant lines, and if found, remove them.

Comment: this gives me "Failed to disable unit: Unit file home-arianhf-googlex2ddrive.mount does not exist."

Comment: @arianhf - check for typos.

Comment: the unit is not enabled, so I can not disable it! yet it takes time in the startup and "fails" to get started.

Comment: You may want to check for a relevant line in /etc/fstab, and if found, comment it out or remove.

Comment: Sorry, @mikewhatever this will not work. `systemctl list-unit-files --state=generated` some services will be generated on the fly.

Comment: @nobody how can I remove those? the home-arianhf-google\x2ddrive.mount                                     does show up in the generated systemctl list.

Comment: you have to check your /etc/fstab as @mikewhatever mentioned.

Comment: ok that worked! @mikewhatever could one of you write an answer so I can choose it as the solution? :)